# Change hidden input value when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, hidden-field

I have a hidden field for state that D&B auto-populates with 2 letter state code. When the form is submitted, I want it to change to the complete state name (ex. NY will become New York). What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `onsubmit` attribute to your `form` element:

```html
<form onsubmit="return changeValue();" id="my-form">
    <input type="hidden" value="NY" id="state-code">
</form>
```

Then add the following javascript:

```js
var stateNames = {
  NY: "New York",
  EG: "Example City"
}

function changeValue() {

  hiddenInput = document.getElementById("state-code")

  currentValue = hiddenInput.value;
  newValue = stateNames[currentValue];

  hiddenInput.value = newValue;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty straight forward. However, state for each form submit varies. How will the javascript identify the state that was abbreviated?

Comment: @Kat Use a javascript object to store the state names and their abbreviations. I've edited the question to suggest how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

you should have object that contains mapping between short and full state name

```
let statesNameMap = {
        NY: 'New York',
        IL: 'Illinois',
}
```

For example formValues is data you are supposed to submit

```
let formValues = {state: 'NY', Name: 'Lorem' }
const handleSubmit = () => {
    formValues.state = stateNameMap[formValues.state];
    // Result: formValues = {state: "New York", Name: "Lorem"}
    // handle submission logic
}
```